# If object's property cannot be hoisted, then why does "var app =exports = module.exports = {};" work at the beginning of module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hoisting

I am a JS newbie poking around Express.js source code trying to hone in on my understanding of finer JS details. I am looking at the main express.js file defining an application here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js

I noticed that the variable app is declared and exported at the top of the file:

```
var app = exports = module.exports = {};
```

And then the properties for app are defined below the above line:

```
app.init = ...
app.defaultConfiguration = ...
app.lazyRouter = ...
```

So it looks like app is exported and then its properties are declared. Does this mean that app's property declarations are hoisted? (ie this is an example of function hoisting) Am I understanding this right?

If you can point me to any documentation that elucidates this problem for me, I would also appreciate it very much!

Comment: No, `app` is not exported. The variable `app` is assigned a reference to the module `exports` object, and then it is used to add properties to the object. (Actually it's more accurate to say that `app` **is** the `exports` object. So it's kind-of exported in that it's the same object.)

Comment: If you're new to JavaScript, poking around a very complex piece of software like Express is probably not the best way to learn how things work. Start systematically learning the language step by step, concept by concept. What you're doing is like learning to drive by jumping in an F1 racer.

Comment: App as reference to the exports object helped me! Thank you. I confused the "module.exports = require("...")" that we often see at the end of js files with this line. I am just done learning the basics and would like to understand stuff like this, prototyping etc in action. Definitely not trying to understand how the entire expressJS codebase works!